# Should I use Scala 2.11.0 or 2.11.8 with Spark 2.3.0?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to upgrade the Spark version from 1.6.2 to 2.3.0. I'm currently using Scala version 2.10, but I need to upgrade to Scala version 2.11.x since Scala 2.10 is no longer supported. My question is which sub-version should I upgrade to? I'm struggling to determine which sub-version to use.

I can't find anything that compares the different sub versions of Scala, but I have encountered some entries that recommend using Scala version 2.11.8 and that there was a bug with Scala 2.11.0 with using Spark (not sure how true that is).

What are your experiences and which sub versions do you recommend? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation says](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/#downloading), you can use a compatible version (2.11.x).
So just use the latest version (2.11.12 as of today).